# Moving state to a separate file in react

Tags: reactjs

I’m new to React and I’ve been experimenting with moving the state of a component to a separate file. I managed to get it working, but I’m unsure if this is considered good practice or if there are better alternatives.

This is the code

Parent component

```js
import "./style.css";
import * as i from "./PackingListStates";

const IslandPackingApp = () => {
  const state = i.usePackingListStates();

  return (
    <>
      <i.Header />
      <i.PackingListForm
        handlePackingFormSubmit={state.handlePackingFormSubmit}
        packingItemDetails={state.packingItemDetails}
        handleFormValueChange={state.handleFormValueChange}
      />
      <i.DisplayPackingList
        packingListItems={state.packingListItems}
        deleteListItem={state.deleteListItem}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default IslandPackingApp;
```

state in a seperate file

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import DisplayPackingList from "./DisplayPackingList";
import PackingListForm from "./PackingListForm";

function usePackingListStates() {
  const [packingItemDetails, setPackingItemDetails] = useState({});

  const [packingListItems, setPackingListItems] = useState([]);

  const handleFormValueChange = (event) => {...};

  const handlePackingFormSubmit = (event) => {...};

  const deleteListItem = (id) => {...};

  return {
    packingItemDetails,
    setPackingItemDetails,
    packingListItems,
    setPackingListItems,
    handleFormValueChange,
    handlePackingFormSubmit,
    deleteListItem,
  };
}

export { Header, DisplayPackingList, PackingListForm, usePackingListStates };
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? If your component is getting too large, it's usually a sign you need to break that component into multiple components rather than spilt the component file into multiple files.

Comment: You need to clear your context properly. there are a few questions which before posting any question you should write to others. why are you doing this, what do you need to achieve? your approach is not bad but I suggest creating custom hooks if that particular component does not belong to a specific component only which means it is only used by a specific component. and the reminder that every time code renders it creates a new component.